# How can I make sure all my table fields can be added in Views?

Tags: views

I have a custom entity. Some of the fields are available to be added from `Structure` `>` `Views`, but some are not available. I already tried adding `default` properties under `hook_schema`, but to no avail. The one particular field I would like to add is of `datetime` type.

The particular field I would like to be available from Views is this:

```
'some_datetime_field' => array(
  'description' => 'some description',
  'type' => 'datetime',
  'mysql_type' => 'datetime',
  'not null' => TRUE,
  'default' => format_date(time(), 'custom', 'Y-m-d 00:00:00')
),
```

Is there some criteria or some sort of guidelines to follow to ensure all the fields of a given entity can be added from Views?

**Update:**

so I thought I had it figured out. It turns out the field is available for adding in Views but column shows empty values.

Here's the code snippet from `hook_views_data_alter`:

```
function my_module_views_data_alter(&$data) {
  $data['my_module_table']['some_datetime_field'] = array(
    'title' => t('Timestamp field'),
'help' => t('Just a timestamp field.'),
'field' => array(
  'handler' => 'views_handler_field_date',
  'click sortable' => TRUE,
),
'sort' => array(
  'handler' => 'views_handler_sort_date',
),
'filter' => array(
  'handler' => 'views_handler_filter_date',
),
  );
}
```

What else am I missing?

Comment: We can but guess until you will show us example. Can you make a "tryout" entity, trimmed down to just 2 fields, one that works and one that does not? And then post here the result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To inform Views about your custom entity's properties, you need to implement [`hook_views_data()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/views/views.api.php/function/hook_views_data/7).

> Describes data tables (or the equivalent) to Views.

Fields are taken care of automatically, so it's just the properties you need to define in your implementation. The documentation page has an abundance of examples so I won't reproduce any code here.

Comment: Interesting. But how come Views is able to show some fields by default without me having to implement `hook_views_data()`?

Comment: The views module (or maybe entity api, I forget) implements a generic solution for _fields_ (as in ones you might create using `field_create_field()`, or through the UI). _Properties_, which aren't fields in Drupal 7, are different, and there's no auto-magic for them. Properties are the ones you define in your entity's base table, and unfortunately you have to add those manually, for now at least.

Comment: Well, that explains it.

Comment: For posterity's sake, I opted to use `hook_views_data_alter` instead so the other fields that have been automatically added are retained.